# Check whether key/value pair exists in hashtable collection

Tags: c#, hashtable

I have hastable

```
Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
hash.Add("a", "1");
hash.Add("b","2");
hash.Add("c","3");
hash.Add("c","4"
```

Now I need to check Key = "c" and value= "3" combination is already exits in hashtable or not.

`hash.ContainsKey` value function cheks weather key is exists or not and `ContainsValue` function checks weather value is exists or not. But if I tried

```
if( hash.Contains("c") && hash.ContainsValue("3"))
{
  // some code heree
}
```

than it will return true for both "c,3" and "c,4" combinathion.

I need to check key/value pair combination how can I check that ?

Comment: Whether the weather be fine, or whether the weather be not, whether the weather be cold or whether the weather be hot, we'll weather the weather whatever the weather, whether we like it or not. (SCNR)

Comment: Really? you can add a duplicated key to a hashtable?! Hashtable is a non-generic dictionary and as far as I know all dictionaries reject duplicated key being added...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(hash.ContainsKey("c") && hash["c"] == "3") { }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check if key exists & then check for the value of the corresponding key.

```
if(hash.ContainsKey("key") && hash["key"] == "3")
{
    // contains key and value
}
```